# What's the best way to slurp the contents of a file into a string in Mathematica?

Tags: string, file-io, file, wolfram-mathematica

I know this is asked commonly but googling doesn't turn up a definitive answer for Mathematica so I thought it would be valuable to have this on StackOverflow.

I've been doing this with Import but it occurred to me that that might be horribly inefficient, Import being such a heavyweight function.

So the question is, can you improve on the following:

```
slurp[filename_] := Import[filename, "Text"]
```

Comment: Not directly related to your performance question, but a few times I needed to slurp XML data and the help files were unhelpful. I found this, in case anyone needs it http://www.hostsrv.com/webMathematica/Resources/Documentation/English/indexE_5_1.html. I plan to post a community question to build an index of Mathematica resources. There is a lot out there, but too scattered.

Answer (score 2):

For importing the entire file at once, the only other option that I am aware of is `ReadList`.  It can be coaxed to returning the entire file as a single string as follows<sup>1</sup>:

```
In[1]:= ReadList["ExampleData/source", Record, RecordSeparators -> {}]
Out[1]:= {"f[x] (: function f :)\r\ng[x] (: function g :)\r\n"}
```

(Note: \r and \n are actually interpreted in the output, but I left them in for readability.) The key is to remove any `RecordSeparators`.  But, I honestly don't think this saves you anything, and `Import[ <file>, "Text"]` is easier to write.   Truthfully, I use `Read[ <file>, String]` when I have data in a format that isn't covered by the type specifiers used in `Read` and `ReadList`, and build a custom function around this operation to load in all of the data.

---

1. You can find this in the [Reading Textual Data tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ReadingTextualData.html).

Comment: Import[file, "String"] uses this ReadList[] syntax to suck in the file. Speed wise, these should be very similar.  The "Text" format does line ending normalization and maybe handles character encodings.

Comment: @Joshua, having not seen the underlying code myself, I suspect you are correct about their relative speeds.  That being said, the `Import` syntax for loading a entire file into a string is much simpler, so it is less likely that bugs will be introduced through its use.  On the other hand, my data is often structured, but not in a way that is handled by `Import`, `Read`, or `ReadList`.  So, I tend to parse the files as I go, as opposed to loading them all at once and then parsing.

Comment: your use of `Read` and `ReadList` sound very sensible.  They both take lists of data types (like a struct) that you might also find useful. Same for their Binary counterparts.

Comment: @Joshua, true, and I use that when I can.  But, if some of the text is markup, and not, strictly speaking, data, then it is less useful.  Personally, I would like to be able to define file formats that `Import`/`Export` could use, so that file formats I use can be treated on par with the built-in types.